# How to convert this to declarative pipeline from scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a code piece in scripted pipeline, that i am looking to convert to declarative pipeline

```
rlsSpec = sprintf(
      readFile('ara-specs/release-spec-template.json'), 
      [currentVersion.contains('SNAPSHOT'), currentVersion.replace('-SNAPSHOT','')])
  writeFile file: 'release-spec.json', text: rlsSpec
  stash includes: '*spec.json', name: 'releaseSpecs'
```

I can readJson and writeJson for the read and write file from scripted, but i am unable to convert the sprintf piece, or i do not have much information on how to convert this piece.

All i am doing in reading a json file, changing the currentVersion to replace the -SNAPSHOT piece and write it back to the json file

Can you please help me convert this piece ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sprintf , all you are doing is reading the json file as a text file and doing String replace. The same thing can be implemented in Declarative Jenkins Pipeline as

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Print'){
            steps {
                script {
                     def inptext = readFile file: "ara-specs/release-spec-template.json" 
                     inptext = inptext.replaceAll("-SNAPSHOT", "")       
                     writeFile file: "release-spec.json", text: inptext
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```